# Интерполяция переменных в шаблон Django

Tags: python, django

```
file = 5
```

Шаблон Django: `<img src="{% static 'mainapp/1/file_1.jpg' %}">`

Как подставить переменную в шаблон, вместо слова "file"?

Comment: Просто `{{ file }}` или что вам нужно?

Comment: Ну и вообще в учебнике про шаблоны всё есть https://djbook.ru/rel3.0/intro/tutorial03.html

Comment: Я же написал, что мне нужно.

Comment: Вставить в шаблон я и сам могу, нужно в url внутри {% static 'mainapp/1/file_1.jpg' %}

Comment: Внутри это как? Какой конкретно результат вы ожидаете на выходе?

Comment: Возможно вам поможет какой-нибудь из этих ответов https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16655851

Comment: да, это то, что нужно

Comment: удалось сделать так: <img src="{% get_static_prefix %}mainapp/1/{{ file}}_1.jpg">

Comment: Спасибо большое

Answer (score 1):

Не думаю что актуально но всё же, может кто-нибудь будет искать.

Я столкнулся с таком проблемой, пришлось выносить в контекст полностью весь путь. Скобки с процентами уже считаются включенной интерполяцией. Дополнительных {{ }} не требуется.

```
path = 'mainapp/1/file_1.jpg'

<img src="{% static path %}">
```